# In-store product scanning with a mobile app

Tags: e-commerce, mobile-application

We are developing a mobile app for a clothing company and one of the features we are implementing is 'Scan in store'.

Basically, when the user is in store, they can use the mobile app to scan a product's bar-code and get more info on it, available sizes, colours, etc.

They will also be presented with 'Add to wishlist' and 'Add to basket' buttons, and the option to pay for the product with ApplePay straight away.

**Question:** Should the user be redirected to the product's own page, or to a separate 'scanned products' page *after scanning the product*?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the person is willing to go through the trouble of scanning the bar code of an item probably means he or she is interested in that particular product, therefore it would be the most logical step to send this person to a page which mainly focuses on this product to give the user more information about it.

You could obviously build both and A/B test it, this is basically the only way to make sure you know for certain what the best way is. Or make a prototype of both and look do some user testing on that, make sure you've got enough data to make a good decision.

Answer (score 1):

If the app also contains the product page then the barcode scanner could be described as a quick way of finding the product within the catalogue - in this case, sending the user to the regular product page would seem to be the most consistent solution.

If, on the other hand, the app does not contain the product page then there is not enough info about the relationship between the product page and the app in your question to offer an answer.

Comment: As a side note, you could also keep a log of items scanned in a separate area so that the user could revisit them later but they would still be shortcuts to the product page

Answer (score 0):

> They will also be presented with 'Add to wishlist' and 'Add to basket' buttons, and the option to pay for the product with ApplePay straight away.

Is it possible to add a choice: "View details"?

So, scanning the barcode would result in a screen with four options:

1. Buy now (ApplePay)
2. Add to basket
3. Add to wishlist
4. View product details

The final option should have a visual indicator that it's navigation rather than action – perhaps add ellipses "..." or an arrow of some kind "»".

Comment: Could be an idea but the thing is, the user might want to check other colours or sizes in stock and it makes sense the take them immediately to the product page or to a specific page; leaving the user on an intermediary screen would simply add an unnecessary step I would say? As it's likely the user would click on 'View Product Details' most of the times anyway.